# How to serialize and deserialize Java Enums as JSON objects with Jackson

Tags: java, enums, jackson

Given an Enum:

```
public enum CarStatus {
    NEW("Right off the lot"),
    USED("Has had several owners"),
    ANTIQUE("Over 25 years old");

    public String description;

    public CarStatus(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

How can we set it up so Jackson can serialize and deserialize an instance of this Enum into and from the following format.

```
{
    "name": "NEW",
    "description": "Right off the lot"
}
```

The default is to simply serialize enums into Strings. For example `"NEW"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Use the `JsonFormat` annotation to get Jackson to deserailze the enum as a JSON object.
2. Create a static constructor accepting a `JsonNode` and annotate said constructor with `@JsonCreator`.
3. Create a getter for the enum's name.

Here's an example.

```
// 1
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.Object)
public enum CarStatus {
    NEW("Right off the lot"),
    USED("Has had several owners"),
    ANTIQUE("Over 25 years old");

    public String description;

    public CarStatus(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // 2
    @JsonCreator
    public static CarStatus fromNode(JsonNode node) {
        if (!node.has("name"))
            return null;

        String name = node.get("name").asText();

        return CarStatus.valueOf(name);
    }

    // 3
    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? 1.8 doesn't seem to allow public static constructors.

Comment: Weird. I'm using Java 1.8 and it does allow public static constructors for  enums.

Comment: copy paste error? Try this: '@JsonCreator
    public static CarStatus fromNode(JsonNode node) {'

Comment: Good catch. Updated example.

Comment: @ncphillips in latest version JsonFormat.Shape.Object should be written as JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT (OBJECT should be all capitals) I think?